# How does Elasticsearch store a float value into an keyword field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created this index:

```json
{
  "users" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "user_id" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I added this entry:

```
PUT users/_doc/1
{
  "user_id": 4.0000
}
```

When I query like this, I always can get this entry

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user_id": {
        "value": 4.0, // not exact same value as I put in
        "boost": 1.0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder why this happens.

Comment: In floating point, trailing zeroes are not significant, 4, 4.0, 4.00, 4.000 etc are all one and the same value.

Comment: I know they are equal mathematically，but when I store them as keyword in Elasticsearch, I think they are not equal.

Comment: I confess, I'm not sure about ES internals, but an unquoted numeric value in JSON is a floating point (a 64-bit double precision), and I assume that ES will first convert it to a double precision and then store that double precision. If you want exact string comparison, you'll need to use `"user_id": "4.0000"` (that is make it a string both in the document and the search).